# Fade in text letter by letter based on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having problems with a functionality that I have to implement, I'm looking to do this (check the second section) -> https://www.jacquemus.com/fr/simon

The letters need to fade in and fade out, based on the scroll, this is what I got so far

```
<div class="ml3">
  <h1>THIS IS MY TEXT THAT IT'S GOING TO SHOW IN SCROLL</h1>
</div>
```

```
:root {
  --percentage: 0;
}

        body {
          background-color: #000;
          margin: 0;
          height: 120vh;
        }

        .ml3 {
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          height: 100vh;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          align-items: center;
        }

        span {
          font-family: Helvetica;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          font-size: 48px;
          color: #fff;
          letter-spacing: -0.3px;
        }

        .ml3 span{
            opacity: var(--percentage);
        }
```

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml3');
    textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

    var letter = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
    var i = 0;
    var currentID = 0;
    var slideCount = letter.length;

    
    document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      let scrolled = document.documentElement.scrollTop / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      
      
      var nextID = currentID + 1;

        if(nextID < slideCount){

            letter[nextID].style.setProperty('--percentage', `${scrolled / 1}` * nextID);
        }
        
        currentID = nextID;
      
    });
```

https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/eYdBbQm

As you can see, it's no near what I want, but I really don't know how to do it, if someone could help me, would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like that effect a lot!! Thank for submitting that question! ;)

So here is a something to help you continue on this challenge.

In the `scroll` handler, I replaced:

```
var nextID = currentID + 1;
if(nextID < slideCount){
  letter[nextID].style.setProperty('--percentage', `${scrolled / 1}` * nextID);
}
currentID = nextID;
```

with:

```
letter.forEach(function (l, i) {
  if (i / letter.length < scrolled) {
    l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 1);
  }else{
    l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 0);
  }
});
```

It compares the scrolled percentage you calculated with the letter index *"percentage"* in the `letter` collection to set it's opacity to 0 or 1.

I would then adjust the scrollHeight of the `body` with the real text to reveal... Below, I used `height: 600vh;` and may be a bit too much. ;)

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".ml3");
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

var letter = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
var i = 0;
var currentID = 0;
var slideCount = letter.length;

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  let scrolled =
    document.documentElement.scrollTop /
    (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  //   var nextID = currentID + 1;

  //   if (nextID < slideCount) {
  //     letter[nextID].style.setProperty(
  //       "--percentage",
  //       `${scrolled / 1}` * nextID
  //     );
  //   }

  //   currentID = nextID;

  letter.forEach(function (l, i) {
    // console.log("====",i / letter.length, i, letter.length)
    if (i / letter.length < scrolled) {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 1);
    } else {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --percentage: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1120vh;
}

.ml3 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

.ml3 span {
  opacity: var(--percentage);
}
```

```html
<div class="ml3">
  <h1>THIS IS MY TEXT THAT IT'S GOING TO SHOW IN SCROLL</h1>
</div>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zYKoexK)

Comment: Hey! that was really helpful, thank you! i managed to do something similar, but it was not the same, I finally found the plug in that they use in the reference website, it's called scrollmagic, so i am going to use that, but again, thank you!