# Scroll to reveal elements one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have elements in an array be consecutively revealed as the user scrolls. I found some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257389/fade-in-text-letter-by-letter-based-on-scroll) which sort of does what I want, and modified it like this:

```js
var unit = document.querySelectorAll("span");
var i = 0;
var currentID = 0;
var slideCount = unit.length;

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  let scrolled =
    document.documentElement.scrollTop /
    (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  unit.forEach(function (l, i) {
    if (i / unit.length < scrolled) {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 1);
    } else {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 0);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --percentage: 0;
}

#reveal span {
  opacity: var(--percentage);
}

body {
  height: 2000px;
}

#reveal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="reveal">
  <span>Scrolling</span>
  <span>should</span>
  <span>reveal</span>
  <span>elements</span>
  <span>one</span>
  <span>by</span>
  <span>one</span>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how I can rework this code so it doesn't rely on the height of the body in order to operate. I'd like to eliminate all scrollbars (which is proving difficult on iOS).

Comment: you need height to be able to scroll. you can remove scroll bar using css.

Comment: @Layhout I tried removing the scrollbar using ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } but it still appears on iOS. I thought maybe moving the scroll function from body to a div might make it easier to remove the scrollbar, but I'm not sure how then to modify the scrollTop calculation.

Comment: to remove scrollbar from body: `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; } body { ms-overflow-style: none; scrollbar-width: none; }`.

Comment: you forgot to select `<body>` when you remove scrollbar (`::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none; }`).

Comment: Thanks @Layhout. I tried all of that and it still shows the scrollbar on iOS. It works on Chrome and Safari though.